# Rails Graphql resolve error: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I created fresh rails app with `graphql`, but had a lot of problems agains guides aged 6+ months. I suspect that `graphql-ruby` changing quite fast.

So my last issue in `resolve` method:

```
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    graphql_name "Root Query"
    description "The query root of this schema"

    field :allProducts, [ProductType], null: false do
      resolve ->(_obj, _args, _ctx) { Product.all }
    end
  end
end
```

Error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 3)
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/graphql-1.9.0.pre1/lib/graphql/schema/field.rb:430:in `resolve'
/Users/alder/Projects/_apps/service_exchange/any-do-api/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:7:in `block in <class:QueryType>'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/graphql-1.9.0.pre1/lib/graphql/schema/field.rb:222:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/graphql-1.9.0.pre1/lib/graphql/schema/field.rb:222:in `initialize'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/graphql-1.9.0.pre1/lib/graphql/schema/member/accepts_definition.rb:142:in `initialize'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/graphql-1.9.0.pre1/lib/graphql/schema/field.rb:88:in `new'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/graphql-1.9.0.pre1/lib/graphql/schema/field.rb:88:in `from_options'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/graphql-1.9.0.pre1/lib/graphql/schema/member/has_fields.rb:52:in `field'
/Users/alder/Projects/_apps/service_exchange/any-do-api/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:6:in `<class:QueryType>'
/Users/alder/Projects/_apps/service_exchange/any-do-api/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:2:in `<module:Types>'
/Users/alder/Projects/_apps/service_exchange/any-do-api/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

[Full log](https://gist.github.com/zishe/4122b8179c056b30af9fa43eb9a3a258)

You  can check out [the full project here](https://github.com/zishe/graphql-rails-test)

I'm using the latest version:

```
gem "graphql", "~> 1.9.0.pre1"
```

But the same error with `1.8.*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, that `resolve` thing doesn't work anymore. Next code works fine:

```
class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
  graphql_name "RootQuery"

  field :categories, [Types::CategoryType], null: false

  def categories
    Category.all
  end
end
```